# Mapping through data assigning to a variable

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

Is there a clean way to fetch API data and set to variables to be used in JSX? Sometimes it looks a bit messy in the JSX as per below:

```
{randomUserData?.results.map((user: any) => (
   <>
    <div>{user.name.first} {user.name.last}</div>
    <img key={user.cell} src={user.picture.large} alt="" />
    <div>{user.location.city}</div>
  </>
 ))}
```

I was thinking something like this could be neater so we don't do any mapping in jsx.

```
    const userFirstName = randomUserData?.results.map((user: any) => (<div>{user.name.first}</div>)
```

Comment: What didn't work in your attempt?

Comment: Renders all user.name.first from the array of 50 results.

Comment: Is that not the intent?  It's not clear what you're asking or what the problem is.  Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to split your logic/data from your template(JSX/HTML) a bit further, you got a couple options to make it more readable:

- The style that you mentioned:

```js
  {randomUserData?.results.map((user) => {
    const firstname = user.name.first;
    const lastname = user.name.last;
    const city = user.location.city;
    const pictureUrl = user.picture.large;
    const cell = user.cell;

    return (
        <>
            <div>{`${firstname} ${lastname}`}</div>
            <img key={cell} src={pictureUrl} alt="" />
            <div>{city}</div>
        </>
    );
})}
```

- Destructure the user object inline

```js
{randomUserData?.results.map(
    ({
        cell,
        location: { city },
        name: { first, last },
        picture: { large },
    }) => (
        <>
            <div>{`${first} ${last}`}</div>
            <img key={cell} src={large} alt="" />
            <div>{city}</div>
        </>
    )
)}
```

I personally go for the second option only if there are not many fields and the object is flat (which is not the case here)